# Can $routeProvider be replaced by $stateProvider or vice versa and how?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I have found a perfectly working and advanced [Angularfire-Seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed) (that encompasses Simple Login). This framework uses `ngRoute` and `$routeProvider` to route the appropriate view and to make sure that certain pages are only shown when the user has logged in.

Now I want to integrate this with the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/), such that I have an Ionic App that uses this Authentication system. However, Ionic uses `$stateProvider`.

My question then becomes: how do I combine these two? I guess one of the two has to go and be replaced by the other. But how do you do this?

Below are the two projects that I want to combine:

**1. Angular-Fire Seed using $routeProvider (routes.js)**

```
  "use strict";

angular.module('myApp.routes', ['ngRoute', 'simpleLogin'])

  .constant('ROUTES', {
    '/home': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // forces the page to wait for this promise to resolve before controller is loaded
        // the controller can then inject `user` as a dependency. This could also be done
        // in the controller, but this makes things cleaner (controller doesn't need to worry
        // about auth status or timing of displaying its UI components)
        user: ['simpleLogin', function(simpleLogin) {
          return simpleLogin.getUser();
        }]
      }
    },
    '/chat': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl'
    },
    '/login': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    },
    '/account': {
      templateUrl: 'partials/account.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      // require user to be logged in to view this route
      // the whenAuthenticated method below will resolve the current user
      // before this controller loads and redirect if necessary
      authRequired: true
    }
  })

  /**
   * Adds a special `whenAuthenticated` method onto $routeProvider. This special method,
   * when called, invokes the requireUser() service (see simpleLogin.js).
   *
   * The promise either resolves to the authenticated user object and makes it available to
   * dependency injection (see AuthCtrl), or rejects the promise if user is not logged in,
   * forcing a redirect to the /login page
   */
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    // credits for this idea: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/dPr9BpIZID0/MgWVluo_Tg8J
    // unfortunately, a decorator cannot be use here because they are not applied until after
    // the .config calls resolve, so they can't be used during route configuration, so we have
    // to hack it directly onto the $routeProvider object
    $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated = function(path, route) {
      route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
      route.resolve.user = ['requireUser', function(requireUser) {
        return requireUser();
      }];
      $routeProvider.when(path, route);
    }
  }])

  // configure views; the authRequired parameter is used for specifying pages
  // which should only be available while logged in
  .config(['$routeProvider', 'ROUTES', function($routeProvider, ROUTES) {
    angular.forEach(ROUTES, function(route, path) {
      if( route.authRequired ) {
        // adds a {resolve: user: {...}} promise which is rejected if
        // the user is not authenticated or fulfills with the user object
        // on success (the user object is then available to dependency injection)
        $routeProvider.whenAuthenticated(path, route);
      }
      else {
        // all other routes are added normally
        $routeProvider.when(path, route);
      }
    });
    // routes which are not in our map are redirected to /home
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
  }])

  /**
   * Apply some route security. Any route's resolve method can reject the promise with
   * { authRequired: true } to force a redirect. This method enforces that and also watches
   * for changes in auth status which might require us to navigate away from a path
   * that we can no longer view.
   */
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'simpleLogin', 'ROUTES', 'loginRedirectPath',
    function($rootScope, $location, simpleLogin, ROUTES, loginRedirectPath) {
      // watch for login status changes and redirect if appropriate
      simpleLogin.watch(check, $rootScope);

      // some of our routes may reject resolve promises with the special {authRequired: true} error
      // this redirects to the login page whenever that is encountered
      $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeError", function(e, next, prev, err) {
        if( angular.isObject(err) && err.authRequired ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      });

      function check(user) {
        // used by the changeEmail functionality so the user
        // isn't redirected to the login screen while we switch
        // out the accounts (see changeEmail.js)
        if( $rootScope.authChangeInProgress ) { return; }
        if( !user && authRequired($location.path()) ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      }

      function authRequired(path) {
        return ROUTES.hasOwnProperty(path) && ROUTES[path].authRequired;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

**2. Ionic Framework (app.js)**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova', 'firebase'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:


  .state('tab.chats', {
      url: '/chats',
      views: {
        'tab-chats': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
          controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
  .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
        controller: 'AccountCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
   .state('tab.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'tab-login': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

})
```

---

*Update (16/01/2015, 10.46)*

I have tried the following (replacing routeProvider by urlRouterProvider), it didnt work (nothing is showing up)

**index.html**, included:

```
 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

**routes.js**

```
"use strict";

angular.module('myApp.routes', ['ngRoute', 'simpleLogin'])

    .constant('ROUTES', {

    '/home': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      resolve: {
        // forces the page to wait for this promise to resolve before controller is loaded
        // the controller can then inject `user` as a dependency. This could also be done
        // in the controller, but this makes things cleaner (controller doesn't need to worry
        // about auth status or timing of displaying its UI components)
        user: ['simpleLogin', function(simpleLogin) {
          return simpleLogin.getUser();
        }]
      },
      authRequired: true
    },
    '/chat': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/chat.html',
      controller: 'ChatCtrl',
      authRequired: true
    },
    '/camera': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/camera.html',
      controller: 'CameraCtrl',
      authRequired: true
    },
    '/login': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    },
    '/account': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/account.html',
      controller: 'AccountCtrl',
      // require user to be logged in to view this route
      // the whenAuthenticated method below will resolve the current user
      // before this controller loads and redirect if necessary
      authRequired: true
    }
  })

  /**
   * Adds a special `whenAuthenticated` method onto $routeProvider. This special method,
   * when called, invokes the requireUser() service (see simpleLogin.js).
   *
   * The promise either resolves to the authenticated user object and makes it available to
   * dependency injection (see AuthCtrl), or rejects the promise if user is not logged in,
   * forcing a redirect to the /login page
   */
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // credits for this idea: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/dPr9BpIZID0/MgWVluo_Tg8J
    // unfortunately, a decorator cannot be use here because they are not applied until after
    // the .config calls resolve, so they can't be used during route configuration, so we have
    // to hack it directly onto the $routeProvider object
    $urlRouterProvider.whenAuthenticated = function(path, route) {
      route.resolve = route.resolve || {};
      route.resolve.user = ['requireUser', function(requireUser) {
        return requireUser();
      }];

      $urlRouterProvider.when(path, route);
    }
  }])




  // configure views; the authRequired parameter is used for specifying pages
  // which should only be available while logged in
  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'ROUTES', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, ROUTES) {

    angular.forEach(ROUTES, function(route, path) {
      if( route.authRequired ) {
        // adds a {resolve: user: {...}} promise which is rejected if
        // the user is not authenticated or fulfills with the user object
        // on success (the user object is then available to dependency injection)
        $urlRouterProvider.whenAuthenticated(path, route);
      }
      else {
        // all other routes are added normally
        $urlRouterProvider.when(path, route);
      }
    });
    // routes which are not in our map are redirected to /home
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');
  }])

  /**
   * Apply some route security. Any route's resolve method can reject the promise with
   * { authRequired: true } to force a redirect. This method enforces that and also watches
   * for changes in auth status which might require us to navigate away from a path
   * that we can no longer view.
   */
  .run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'simpleLogin', 'ROUTES', 'loginRedirectPath',
    function($rootScope, $location, simpleLogin, ROUTES, loginRedirectPath) {
      // watch for login status changes and redirect if appropriate
      simpleLogin.watch(check, $rootScope);

      // some of our routes may reject resolve promises with the special {authRequired: true} error
      // this redirects to the login page whenever that is encountered
      $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(e, next, prev, err) {
        if( angular.isObject(err) && err.authRequired ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      });

      function check(user) {
        // used by the changeEmail functionality so the user
        // isn't redirected to the login screen while we switch
        // out the accounts (see changeEmail.js)
        if( $rootScope.authChangeInProgress ) { return; }
        if( !user && authRequired($location.path()) ) {
          $location.path(loginRedirectPath);
        }
      }

      function authRequired(path) {
        return ROUTES.hasOwnProperty(path) && ROUTES[path].authRequired;
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. It's not quite a search and replace, but nearly. $routeProvider.when -> $stateProvider.state, $routeChangeStart -> $stateChangeStart, $routeChangeSuccess -> $stateChangeSuccess, and $routeChangeError -> $stateChangeError. Remove the leading / in ROUTES and add a url: parameter which matches the current keys.

Comment: That seems very complicated. Can't we replace routeProvider by urlRouterProvider instead? I have tried (see update of code), but it didnt work. Perhaps suggestions on that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with $urlRouteProvider. Maybe somebody with more experience will chime in.